# How to run a function when terminal width is changed in powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, triggers, prompt

I customized my prompt and now it has a right-aligned part, but the terminal screen messed up if I changed the width of it:

[image: before resizing]

[image: after resizing]

So I want powershell to run a function to clear this mess every time the terminal window width is changed. How can I achieve this?

Comment: the only thing i can think of is to add code to your prompt function to calc the terminal size.

Comment: Form controls have an [Anchor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.anchor) property. Use that.

Comment: Are there any events I can use?